# Load CSS dynamic, with dynamic pages made with PHP

Tags: php, html, css

I could not find any questions about this topic, so therefor I am asking here.

I have a PHP site, splitted up into header.php & footer.php.
In the header.php i have my CSS files, but I have some subfolders, that it should load from, but I can't find any way how.

I tried using

```
<?php echo "http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>
```

as a baseurl, but it would just include the localhost into the directory of the css file.

How can i do?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you use "relative" links to the content? For instance, `<img src="/mydir/anotherdir/myimage.jpg">` will search for the image at `/mydir/anotherdir` keeping the domain name and even the scheme or the port if you are using any.

Comment: Because it's in the subfolder. For example, i have login & register pages under /portal, and the login.php uses the header.php and the footer.php. And it should use the primary css file, in the primary folder. :-)